# Error trying to run XDP on my device driver

Tags: linux, networking, ebpf

I'm trying to figure out how to run a XDP code:

```
#include <linux/bpf.h>
int main() {
    return XDP_PASS;
}
```

I'm trying to have XDP drop all the packets.
So I compiled it as :

```
clang -target bpf -c xdp.c -o xdp.o
```

and my interface name is enp5s0.

So I tried to sort of attach the code to that interface by typing :

```
ip -force link set dev enp5s0 xdpdrv obj xdp.o sec .text
```

Then I get the following error :

```
mkdir /sys/fs/bpf/tc/ failed: Permission denied
Continuing without mounted eBPF fs. Too old kernel?


Prog section '.text' rejected: Operation not permitted (1)!
- Type:          6
- Instructions:  2 (0 over limit)
- License :

Verifier analysis:

Error fetching program/map!
```

and I have no idea what is wrong.. I'm trying to get a hold of XDP and I've been trying to fix this problem for three days but no result.... I would really appreciate it if you guys would help me out!

Comment: What is the kernel version? Does your driver support xdp?  Is xdp support enabled in kernel?

Comment: I updated the kernel to the latest version but I totally forgot I have to check the driver support and the kernel enabling statues. Thank you so much! I'm new to this so I keep making basic mistakes.. :((

Comment: Also make sure you have a recent version of `ip` (package `iproute2`).

Answer (score 0):

can you check kernel version . it should be above 4.8

Answer (score 0):

Do you run `ip`as superuser? Can you try to run `ip -force link set dev enp5s0 xdp obj xdp.o sec .text` instead of `ip -force link set dev enp5s0 xdpdrv obj xdp.o sec .text`? The first use xdp in best effort mode. Maybe your device driver doesn't support XDP-driver.
Another tip: you can specify the section of code you want with `SEC("name_section")` and then you use `name_section` instead of `.text`

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount bpffs before attaching XDP program.

```
mount bpffs /sys/fs/bpf -t bpf
```